# program crashing with segmentation fault while calling a callback function

Tags: c, callback, segmentation-fault

My program crashes with Segmentation fault while calling a callback function randomly. When I analyzed the core the callback function address is 0x20202020. 
Program terminated with signal 11, Segmentation fault.

```
#0  0x20202020 in ?? ()

(gdb) bt

#0  0x20202020 in ?? ()
#1  0xf775a8cf in my_function (parm_p=0x9b88020) at ../src/mewz.c:1395

(mqheader_p->mqh_callback)(mqheader_p->mqh_cbarg);

mqh_callback = 0x20202020,
mqh_cbarg = 0x20202020,
```

This is happening randomly.
I understand the 0x20202020 is not a valid address of the call back function, but why this callback function address is randomly pointing to an invalid address. Any Clues?

Comment: You'll want to tag this question with the language you are writing your program in.

Comment: The mqheader_p variable is uninitialised or has been overwritten, probably by some stringpointer value.

Comment: The code is written in "C" language. (mqheader_p->mqh_callback) is the callback function pointer.

Answer (score 2):

The callback function pointer has probably been overwritten, or is being used from memory which is not even properly allocated and initialized.

It's somewhat interesting that 0x20 is the ASCII code for the space character.

Things to do:

1. Inspect the code around the allocation of the data  `mqheader_p` points at.
2. Run the program in a debugger, and set a watchpoint on the function pointer.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is buffer over run. Because 0x20 happens to be ASCII space, I think this is part of a string overwriting the address. Look at your use of sprintf and the like in particuar.

You could log the memory before and after which may give you more of a clue which string could be overwritting.

NB: 0x20202020 is four bytes 0x20 0x20 0x20 0x20 or 4 space characters in a row.

Comment: It is not exactly 0x20, it is 0x20202020

Comment: In a previous core file the value is 0x57

Comment: You are looking at 4 bytes at once with the pointer so that is 4 spaces in a row. 0x57 is the 'W' character, look at an [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/).

Answer (score 0):

To bug such kind of issue, I think you can print out the mqh_callback value after the first initilization  of mqh_callback and another print out should be just at before you call callback. 
Aonther is to use write breakpoint on the address of mqh_callback.

such kind of error may come from some pointer trick operation such as missing initilization, buffer over flow and so on.

Comment: Hi wbao, Thanks for the reply.
I tried printing those values while assigning and before invoking the callback. For hunderds of times both values are same. But at certain point of time before invokation of callback function this value became 0x20202020. And this is within a thread start function.

Comment: I am not sure if your env support or not. the GDB has awatch command to let you watch a write memory access on specific virutal address. How about to use this to trace "the evil" ? this may be a easy way to find who change your function pointer

Comment: Hi Wbao, The problem is this is occuring in client environment. And one more interesting thing is this has numurous client installations where it is not crashing. Only for one customer it is randomly crashing.

Comment: Interesting... What I can think is to compare the env of the pass sample and failure sample. However it is a little hard.